# Pyramid of asterisk using while loop in java

Tags: java

Is there possibilities that while loop can make a pyramid of asterisk in java?

```
    int num,num_ast;
    String asterisk= "*";

    Scanner pal = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter number of asterisk: ");
    num_ast = pal.nextInt();

    num=0;
    while(num < num_ast)
    {
        System.out.println(asterisk);
        asterisk += "*";
        num++;
    }
```

this line only creates a right triangle of asterisk. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. Think how you would that manually, when you can only print characters on one line (including new lines), without going backwards. You see, the point of your homework is that you spend many hours thinking about it. Delegating that part to other people defeats the purpose of learning. You learn best by trying yourself first.

Comment: Think of printing one line on each loop, instead of one character

Comment: Graph paper might be your friend here.  Sketch out pyramid using one star per grid cell.   Number the lines starting from zero.  You'll find there are patterns that relate the pyramid height and the line number to the number of initial blanks and the number of stars to be printed on each line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think of your pyramid as drawn on a coordinate system. You need to make sure that both the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate move in the whole program.

```
Scanner pal = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of rows you want");
int n = pal.nextInt();
int rows = 0;
while (rows < n)
{
    int column = 0;
    while (column < n - rows)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
        column++;
    }
    int currentStars = 0;
    while (currentStars <= rows)
    {
        System.out.print(" *"); 
        currentStars++;
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    rows++;
}
```

This should get your program running. However, take time to understand why this works.